# "Cannot locate configuration source" when using commons-configuration XMLConfiguration with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons

I'm building two apps that uses commons-configuration XMLConfiguration. Since the apps are related, I've build another project, called commons, that has a custom configuration manager that initializes the XMLConfiguration like so:

```
config = new XMLConfiguration("conf/config.xml");
```

What happens is that the "command-line" app works fine, loading the configuration file. But when I try to use my custom configuration manager on a webapp (using Tomcat) I get a

> org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source

I've placed the conf directory on the WEB-INF folder, the root folder and the META-INF folder. I've also tried with `"/conf/config.xml"`, `"./conf/config.xml"` and `"../conf/config.xml"`.

The only time I got this to work - on the web app - was using an absolute path.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(..)`, and pass the stream. Or if the file is on the classpath, you can use [`getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Hi bozho, Thanks for you response,but how do I get the ServletContext from a webservice? (sorry but i'm a java newbie :P)

Comment: I've tried:
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
And on the webservice constructor: ServletContext servletContext =
                        (ServletContext) context.getMessageContext().get(
                                        MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT); But I get the context null.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration` does not have a constructor which accepts an `InputStream`, so `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` will not work.  There is an `XMLConfiguration` constructor which takes a URL, however, so use `getClass().getResource()` instead.

See http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html